# What is my actual motherboard?

Tags: hardware, hp, motherboard

Ubuntu reports in dmesg:

```
DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP ProDesk 490 G1 MT/18EB, BIOS L02 v02.01 09/22/2013
```

But I cannot find information about this **[motherboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard)** anywhere.

I do can check (almost) every single piece of hardware (various chips, the controllers, the ethernet, the audio and so on) but that's not the motherboard. Every motherboard make and model is actually unique.

Whatever tool I'd use I wouldn't get any more details from what the kernel.

I do know what is my hardware (read the quoted text). I simply don't know anything more than the bare name.

I would like to know, for example, the chipset brand/model and other MB-related stuff. No way, no matter the tool I use.

How can I know details about the **motherboard** I am using without opening the case?

Is there anyone knowing anything about it?
Or simply, this cannot be done even in the twenty first century?

Comment: `hardinfo`, which is mentioned in the duplicate, will give you this information in the Devices => DMI => Board section.

Comment: hardinfo doesn't provide any extra information. It's output about DMI is exactly the same as shown in the kernel bood diagnostics.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to view motherboard information on your Ubuntu box

```
sudo dmidecode -t 2
```

You might need to install this tool if not available

```
sudo apt-get install dmidecode
```

Comment: Same information as shown in the kernel bood diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into your sysfs for DMI informations, the motherboard name should be available using the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_name
```

There is a lot of files under `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/` that could be useful too:

```
ls /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/
./         bios_vendor      board_name    board_version      chassis_type     modalias      product_serial   subsystem@
../        bios_version     board_serial  chassis_asset_tag  chassis_vendor   power/        product_uuid     sys_vendor
bios_date  board_asset_tag  board_vendor  chassis_serial     chassis_version  product_name  product_version  uevent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at BIOS information with `dmidecode`.

```
sudo apt-get install dmidecode
sudo dmidecode | less
```

In there you should have something like this (this is mine):

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: X58A-UD7
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number:
```

Though I suspect in your case you're just going to see the same as the DMI line. That's probably because your motherboard and its BIOS are custom made by HP for purpose. Not available in the shops, etc.

Comment: maybe a simple command `sudo dmidecode | sed -n '/.*Base Board Information.*/,+13p'` does this.